# NFL players with at least 5 Super Bowl rings

Tags: american-football, trivia, history, nfl, super-bowl

The New England Patriots beat the Atlanta Falcons in overtime of Super Bowl 51 (2017) to win the Lombardi Trophy. This makes Tom Brady (the quarterback of the New England Patriots) the first Quarterback to win 5 Super Bowls. How many players in any position have won at least 5 rings, strictly as a player?

Comment: Related: [Which world leader holds the record for the most Super Bowl rings held?](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/heres-how-vladimir-putin-stole-a-super-bowl-ring-from-the-patriots-robert-kraft/)

Comment: @CodeNewbie You're confused that wasn't stealing that was [civil forfeiture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States) Putin was just reading up on US law and decided it was a cool tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_ring) on Super Bowl Rings, at least 24 people have 5+ rings.  However, only 2 have 5+ rings as players:

> - Charles Haley (two with San Francisco and three with Dallas, all as a player)
> - Tom Brady (five as quarterback of New England)

In addition, three of the people who have 5 or more rings have some of them as a player.